# AWS Directory Service Join a Linux Instance

Tags: linux, active-directory, amazon-web-services

I followed the AWS documentation to manually join Linux instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/join_linux_instance.html#linux_connect.

I am able to login with AD user's and performing `sudo` access in Linux VM.
But when I try to setup Restricting Account Login Access, I am facing issues.

```
config file : /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

============================
domains = example.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
http://domain/example.com
ad_domain = example.com
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
ad_access_filter = (memberOf=cn=dev,ou=Users,ou=exmaple,dc=example,dc=com)
============================================
dev=groupname
ou=group is located in Users Organizational Unit.
============================================
errors: remote side unexpectedly closed the network
 sshd pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=182.72.147.2 user=user1@example.com
 sshd pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user user1@example.com: 6 (Permission denied)
 sshd Failed password for user1@example.com from 167.09.198.8 port 52519 ssh2
 sshd fatal: Access denied for user user1@example.com by PAM account configuration
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: The config you posted is using `example.com` as the server. Do you have an active directory server set up, and have you tried updating the config to point at it?

Comment: yes, I am using aws Active Directory service, its working fine,i am able to login with AD user's in windows and linux vm, but i want  to setup group Restricting Account Login Access via sssd. 
i am getting fatal: Access denied for user user1@example.com by PAM account configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually intended to use `example.com`, then you have a typo in your `ad_access_filter` setting: `ou=exmaple`